# What is the right categorical framework for diagonal approximations, cup and cap products and identities between them?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, monoidal-categories

I wanted to know what is the right categorical analog for the diagonal approximation for the singular chain complex $\Delta: C\rightarrow C\otimes C$ as a morphism in the homotopy category of chain complexes such that the identities between cup and cap products hold.

I was thinking about the comonoid objects in the closed monoidal categories, where you can create caps and cups, but to have standart $identities$ between caps and cups as is in the situation of the singular chain complexes it is not enough to have triangle and cocomutativity coherence conditions for the comonoid object $C$. So I am interested to know better framework.

Comment: Well, what I have in mind is the diagonal approximation for the singular chain complex in as a particular case of comonoid object in the homotopy category of chain complexes. Then you have several nice identities relating caps , cups and evaluations in this particular case. That was the motivation for the question.

Comment: You're moving in a less general framework so the should be no more conditions.

Comment: Let me put it this way: some coherence conditions which would guarantee analogs of identities between caps and cups in the case of diagonal approximations for the singular chain complex.

Comment: @DmitriScheglov that is extra structure, and not extra properties. Maybe you should reformulate your whole question. BTW, Tsygan-Tamarkin's notion of 'calculus' may be interesting for you.

Comment: @FernandoMuro, could you give me a good reference to take a look at this calculus? Yes, I am thinking on how to reformulate it better.

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/noncommutative%20differential%20calculus